# Reading multiple derived classes from a file c++

Tags: file, c++11

My program consists at managing a stock of products of different types.
I created 3 different classes for each product derived from a base class.
I implemented a variable that describes each type as a string since type_id dosent work for my compiler.
In the file i am saving each line contains a product. The first string is dedicated for the type of product. From there the data will be implemented in a table as an object of the class type.
I tried every possible way i know but it always reades falsly and the program bugs.
Remarque: each time i use getline or seekg the program bugs.
So here is my code: (Excuse the length of it but i cant spare any line in order to reproduce the error)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Produit
{
public:
    string codeABarre;
    string libelle;
    string cltype;
    long int qte;
    string tempsDeStockage;
    int coutDeStockage;
    int prixDachat;
    string dateDentree;
    string tempsMaxDeStockage;
   string getcodeABarre()
    {
    return codeABarre;
    }
    Produit();
    Produit(string , string ,long int ,string , int ,int , string ,  string );
    string getLibelle();
    long int getQte();
    string getTempsDeStockage();
    int getCoutDeStockage();
    int getPrixDachat();
    string getDateDentree();
    string getTempsMaxDeStockage();
    string getCltype();
    void setcodeABarre(string);
    void setLibelle(string );
    void setQte(long int);
    void setTempsDeStockage(string);
    void setCoutDeStockage(int);
    void setPrixDachat(int);
    void setDateDentree(string);
    void setTempsMaxDeStockage(string);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Produit*);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Produit&);

};
Produit::Produit(string cab, string lib,long int q,string tds, int cds,int pda, string de,  string tmds)
{
    codeABarre=cab;
    libelle=lib;
    qte=q;
    tempsDeStockage=tds;
    coutDeStockage=cds;
    prixDachat=pda;
    dateDentree=de;
    tempsMaxDeStockage=tmds;
}
Produit::Produit()
{

}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& flux,Produit* p)
{
    flux<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<p->getcodeABarre()<<" "<<p->getLibelle()<<" "<<p->getQte()<<" "<<p->getTempsDeStockage()<<" "<<p->
    getCoutDeStockage()<<" "<<p->getPrixDachat()<<" "<<p->getDateDentree()<<" "<<p->getTempsMaxDeStockage()<<endl;
    return flux;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& flux, Produit& p)
{
    flux>>p.cltype>>p.codeABarre>>p.libelle>>p.qte>>p.tempsDeStockage>>p.coutDeStockage>>p.prixDachat>>p.dateDentree>>p.tempsMaxDeStockage;
    return flux ;
}
class Souris : public Produit{
 string marque;
  int dpi;
  string type;
public :
    Souris();
    Souris(string , string ,long int ,string , int ,int , string ,  string ,string ,int , string );
    string getMarque()
    {
        return marque;
    };
    int getDpi();
    string getType();
    void setMarque(string);
    void setDpi(int);
    void setType(string);
    void affichesr(Souris*);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Souris*);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,Souris&);


};
Souris::Souris( string codeABarre1, string libelle1,long int qte1,string tempsDeStockage1, int coutDeStockage1,
               int prixDachat1, string dateDentree1,  string tempsMaxDeStockage1,string marque1,int dpi1,
               string type1):Produit(codeABarre1,libelle1,qte1, tempsDeStockage1,  coutDeStockage1, prixDachat1
                                      ,dateDentree1, tempsMaxDeStockage1)
{
   marque=marque1;
    dpi=dpi1;
    type=type1;
    cltype="Souris";
}
Souris::Souris()
{
    cltype="Souris";
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& flux,Souris* p)
{
    flux<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<p->getcodeABarre()<<" "<<p->getLibelle()<<" "<<p->getQte()<<" "<<p->getTempsDeStockage()<<" "<<p->
    getCoutDeStockage()<<" "<<p->getPrixDachat()<<" "<<p->getDateDentree()<<" "<<p->getTempsMaxDeStockage()<<" "<<p->
    getMarque()<<" "<<p->getDpi()<<" "<<p->getType()<<endl;

    return flux;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& flux,Souris& p)
{
    flux>>p.cltype>>p.codeABarre>>p.libelle>>p.qte>>p.tempsDeStockage>>p.coutDeStockage>>p.prixDachat>>p.dateDentree>>p.tempsMaxDeStockage>>p.marque>>p.dpi>>p.type;

    return flux;
}
class PC : public Produit
 {
    string marque;
    int hdd;
    int ssd;
    string processor;
    int vram;
    int ram;
    string vcard;
    string type;
public:
    PC();
    PC(string , string ,long int ,string , int ,int , string ,  string,string,int,int,string,int,int,string,string);
    string getMarque()
    {
        return marque;
    }
    int getHdd();
    int getSsd();
    string getProcessor();
    int getVram();
    int getRam();
    string getVcard();
    string getType();
    void setMarque(string);
    void setHdd(int);
    void setSsd(int);
    void setProcessor(string);
    void setVram(int);
    void setRam(int);
    void setVcard(string);
    void setType(string);
    void affichepc(PC*);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,PC*);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,PC&);
};
PC::PC(string codeABarre1, string libelle1,long int qte1,string tempsDeStockage1, int coutDeStockage1,int prixDachat1,
string dateDentree1,  string tempsMaxDeStockage1,string marque1,int hdd1,int ssd1,string processor1,int vram1,
int ram1,string vcard1,string type1):Produit(codeABarre1,libelle1,qte1, tempsDeStockage1,coutDeStockage1, prixDachat1,
                                             dateDentree1, tempsMaxDeStockage1)
{
    marque=marque1;
    hdd=hdd1;
    ssd=ssd1;
    processor=processor1;
    vram=vram1;
    ram=ram1;
    vcard=vcard1;
    type=type1;
    cltype="PC";
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& flux,PC* p)
{
    flux<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<" "<<p->getcodeABarre()<<" "<<p->getLibelle()<<" "<<p->getQte()<<" "<<p->getTempsDeStockage()
    <<" "<<p->getCoutDeStockage()<<" "<<p->getPrixDachat()<<" "<<p->getDateDentree()<<" "<<p->getTempsMaxDeStockage()<<" "<<p->
    getMarque()<<" "<<p->getHdd()<<" "<<p->getSsd()<<" "<<p->getProcessor()<<" "<<p->getRam()<<" "<<p->getVcard()<<" " <<p->
    getVram()<<" "<<p->getType()<<endl;
    return flux;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& flux,PC& p)
{
    flux>>p.cltype>>p.codeABarre>>p.libelle>>p.qte>>p.tempsDeStockage>>p.coutDeStockage>>p.prixDachat>>p.dateDentree>>p.tempsMaxDeStockage>>p.marque>>p.hdd>>p.ssd>>p.processor>>p.ram>>p.vcard>>p.vram>>p.type;
    return flux;
}
class ProduitAlimentaire: public Produit
{
    string type;
    string dlc;
public:
    ProduitAlimentaire();
    ProduitAlimentaire (string , string ,long int ,string , int ,int , string ,  string ,string,string);
    string getType()
    {
        return type;
    };
    void setType(string);
    string getDLC();
    void setDLC(string);
    void affichepa(ProduitAlimentaire*);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,ProduitAlimentaire*);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,ProduitAlimentaire&);

};
ProduitAlimentaire::ProduitAlimentaire( string codeABarre1, string libelle1,long int qte1,string tempsDeStockage1, int coutDeStockage1,int prixDachat1, string dateDentree1,  string tempsMaxDeStockage1,string type1,string dlc1)
:Produit(codeABarre1,libelle1,qte1, tempsDeStockage1,  coutDeStockage1, prixDachat1,  dateDentree1, tempsMaxDeStockage1)
{
    type=type1;
    dlc=dlc1;
    cltype="ProduitAlimentaire";
}
ProduitAlimentaire::ProduitAlimentaire()
{
    cltype="ProduitAlimentaire";
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& flux,ProduitAlimentaire* p)
{
        flux<<p->getCltype()<<" "<<p->getcodeABarre()<<" "<<p->getLibelle()<<" "<<p->getQte()<<" "<<p->getTempsDeStockage()
        <<" "<<p->getCoutDeStockage()<<" "<<p->getPrixDachat()<<" "<<p->getDateDentree()<<" "<<p->getTempsMaxDeStockage()<<" "
        <<p->getType()<<" "<<p->getDLC()<<endl;
    return flux;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& flux,ProduitAlimentaire& p)
{
    flux>>p.cltype>>p.codeABarre>>p.libelle>>p.qte>>p.tempsDeStockage>>p.coutDeStockage>>p.prixDachat>>p.dateDentree>>p.tempsMaxDeStockage>>p.type>>p.dlc;
    return flux;
}
int main()
{
  system("color F1");
  int choix;
  string num,add;
  cout<<"Tapez le numero du depot :"<<endl;
  cin>>num;
  cout<<"Tapez l'addresse du depot : "<<endl;
  cin>>add;
  Depot depo(num,add);
  ifstream fi("Produits.txt",ios::in);
  if (fi.is_open())
  {
      do
      {
          string type;
          fi>>type;
          if(type=="ProduitAlimentaire")
          {
              ProduitAlimentaire* pa=new ProduitAlimentaire();
              fi>>(*pa);
              if (pa->getcodeABarre()!="0")
              {
                  depo.ajouterAliment(pa);
              }
          }
          else if (type=="Souris")
          {
              Souris* sr=new Souris();
              fi>>(*sr);
              if (sr->getcodeABarre()!="0")
              {
                  depo.ajouterSouris(sr);
              }
          }
          else if (type=="PC")
          {
              PC* pc=new PC();
              fi>>(*pc);
              if (pc->getcodeABarre()!="0")
              {
                  depo.ajouterPC(pc);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              cout<<" can't read any type of products" <<endl;
          }
      }
      while(!fi.eof());
  }
  fi.close();
ofstream fo;
fo.open("Produits.txt",ios::out|ios::trunc);
if (fo)
{
    for(int i=0;i<depo.nbrProduits;i++)
    {
        string type=depo.lesProduits[i]->getCltype();
        if(type=="ProduitAlimentaire")
          {
              ProduitAlimentaire* pa=(ProduitAlimentaire*)(depo.lesProduits[i]);
              fo<<pa;
          }
          else if (type=="Souris")
          {
              Souris* sr=(Souris*)(depo.lesProduits[i]);
              fo<<sr;
          }
          else if (type=="PC")
          {
              PC* pc=(PC*)(depo.lesProduits[i]);
              fo<<pc;
          }
    }
}
fo.close();
return 0;
};
```

Comment: I would suggest you include the "bugs" or errors you are experiencing so we can better help you.

Comment: Also, I'm sure you can reduce the size of the code you posted. Remove all members from all classes. Make all the classes empty. Whatever your bug is, it's unlikely to be because of the number of the members in each class. Removing all those members, and all the massive code tha declares, reads, and writes them, is going to reduce the size of this chunk by at least 90%.

Comment: the bug is that the reading from the file is wrong and the console stops working immediately.
I cant take away any member due to the importance of each one.
The whole code is like 1370 lines and all is relevant .